# automatic disconnection of RAID array

Tags: usb, raid, usb-drive, external-hdd

A RAID array connected to my system (Debian 7) via USB frequently disconnects itself for no apparent reason. Upon initial connection to the system, the device is detected, and the array can be initialized, mounted, read from, written to, and unmounted quite normally. However, invariably, after a short period of time (minutes to hours), the component disks disappear from `/dev` and from the listing of `fdisk -l`, and remain inaccessible until the device (i.e., RAID enclosure) is power cycled.

Judging from the output of `/var/log/messages`, the problem appears to be resetting of the USB device. After the unprovoked reset, the system repeatedly attempts to reconnect the device, assigning a higher USB device number, eventually terminating after five reset attempts.

What is responsible for the device resetting itself? I suspect the fault lies with the USB controller. How can the undesired auto-reset behavior be avoided?

The following excerpts from `/var/log/messages` show the typical behavior of the array after initialization and subsequent reset:

Initial connection:

```
Jun 19 19:38:51 hostname kernel: [406823.308418] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 24 using ehci_hcd
Jun 19 19:38:51 hostname kernel: [406823.401317] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=2351
Jun 19 19:38:51 hostname kernel: [406823.401330] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
Jun 19 19:38:51 hostname kernel: [406823.401338] usb 1-1.3: Product: USB to ATA/ATAPI Bridge
Jun 19 19:38:51 hostname kernel: [406823.401345] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: JMicron
Jun 19 19:38:51 hostname kernel: [406823.401350] usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: DCC3..........
Jun 19 19:38:51 hostname kernel: [406823.402469] scsi16 : usb-storage 1-1.3:1.0
Jun 19 19:38:51 hostname mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 24: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3"
Jun 19 19:38:51 hostname mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 24 was not an MTP device
Jun 19 19:38:52 hostname kernel: [406824.400835] scsi 16:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WDC WD20 EFRX-68AX9N0          PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
Jun 19 19:38:52 hostname kernel: [406824.401450] scsi 16:0:0:1: Direct-Access     WDC WD20 EFRX-68AX9N0          PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
Jun 19 19:38:52 hostname kernel: [406824.402433] sd 16:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
Jun 19 19:38:52 hostname kernel: [406824.402583] sd 16:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
Jun 19 19:38:52 hostname kernel: [406824.662288] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdd] 3907029168 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.81 TiB)
Jun 19 19:38:52 hostname kernel: [406824.662789] sd 16:0:0:1: [sde] 3907029168 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.81 TiB)
Jun 19 19:38:52 hostname kernel: [406824.663573] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
Jun 19 19:38:52 hostname kernel: [406824.664356] sd 16:0:0:1: [sde] Write Protect is off
Jun 19 19:38:52 hostname kernel: [406824.665087] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdd] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Jun 19 19:38:52 hostname kernel: [406824.666295] sd 16:0:0:1: [sde] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Jun 19 19:38:52 hostname kernel: [406824.705355]  sdd: sdd1
Jun 19 19:38:52 hostname kernel: [406824.740148]  sde: sde1
Jun 19 19:38:52 hostname kernel: [406824.743667] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
Jun 19 19:38:52 hostname kernel: [406824.746756] sd 16:0:0:1: [sde] Attached SCSI disk
```

Upon reset:

```
Jun 19 20:05:25 hostname kernel: [408416.587392] usb 1-1.3: reset high-speed USB device number 24 using ehci_hcd
Jun 19 20:05:25 hostname kernel: [408416.679688] usb 1-1.3: device firmware changed
Jun 19 20:05:25 hostname kernel: [408416.679852] sd 16:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
Jun 19 20:05:25 hostname kernel: [408416.679942] usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 24
Jun 19 20:05:25 hostname kernel: [408416.767366] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 25 using ehci_hcd
Jun 19 20:05:25 hostname kernel: [408416.860214] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=2351
Jun 19 20:05:25 hostname kernel: [408416.860225] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
Jun 19 20:05:25 hostname kernel: [408416.860232] usb 1-1.3: Product: USB to ATA/ATAPI Bridge
Jun 19 20:05:25 hostname kernel: [408416.860237] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: JMicron
Jun 19 20:05:25 hostname kernel: [408416.860241] usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: 152D.............
Jun 19 20:05:25 hostname kernel: [408416.861634] scsi17 : usb-storage 1-1.3:1.0
Jun 19 20:05:25 hostname mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 25: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3"
Jun 19 20:05:25 hostname mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 25 was not an MTP device
Jun 19 20:05:47 hostname kernel: [408438.591825] usb 1-1.3: reset high-speed USB device number 25 using ehci_hcd
Jun 19 20:05:57 hostname kernel: [408448.750695] usb 1-1.3: reset high-speed USB device number 25 using ehci_hcd
Jun 19 20:06:02 hostname kernel: [408453.911854] usb 1-1.3: reset high-speed USB device number 25 using ehci_hcd
Jun 19 20:06:03 hostname kernel: [408454.359608] usb 1-1.3: reset high-speed USB device number 25 using ehci_hcd
Jun 19 20:06:03 hostname kernel: [408454.807394] usb 1-1.3: reset high-speed USB device number 25 using ehci_hcd
Jun 19 20:06:04 hostname kernel: [408455.295168] usb 1-1.3: reset high-speed USB device number 25 using ehci_hcd
Jun 19 20:06:04 hostname kernel: [408455.711201] scsi 17:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
Jun 19 20:06:04 hostname kernel: [408455.711448] usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 25
Jun 19 20:06:04 hostname kernel: [408455.786917] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 26 using ehci_hcd
Jun 19 20:06:05 hostname kernel: [408456.234679] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 27 using ehci_hcd
Jun 19 20:06:05 hostname kernel: [408456.686418] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 28 using ehci_hcd
Jun 19 20:06:06 hostname kernel: [408457.174018] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 29 using ehci_hcd
```

Attempted assignment of USB device number 29 is the final attempt to revive the disk array. To reconnect the device at this point, power cycling of the RAID enclosure or disconnect/reconnect is mandatory.

Update:
Recently, the device appeared to reset shortly after a resync. I'm not sure if this is helpful, but the error messages contained in `/var/log/messages` are included below:

```
    Jul  5 02:55:02 hdac kernel: [135732.758796] md: md0: resync done.
Jul  5 03:12:04 hdac kernel: [136754.176970] usb 1-1.3: reset high-speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
Jul  5 03:12:04 hdac kernel: [136754.269537] usb 1-1.3: device firmware changed
Jul  5 03:12:04 hdac kernel: [136754.269995] usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 10
Jul  5 03:12:04 hdac kernel: [136754.269998] sd 6:0:0:1: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
Jul  5 03:12:04 hdac kernel: [136754.348882] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci_hcd
Jul  5 03:12:04 hdac kernel: [136754.442408] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=2351
Jul  5 03:12:04 hdac kernel: [136754.442419] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
Jul  5 03:12:04 hdac kernel: [136754.442425] usb 1-1.3: Product: USB to ATA/ATAPI Bridge
Jul  5 03:12:04 hdac kernel: [136754.442430] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: JMicron
Jul  5 03:12:04 hdac kernel: [136754.442434] usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: 152D....
Jul  5 03:12:04 hdac kernel: [136754.443581] scsi7 : usb-storage 1-1.3:1.0
Jul  5 03:12:04 hdac mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 11: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3"
Jul  5 03:12:04 hdac mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 11 was not an MTP device
Jul  5 03:12:26 hdac kernel: [136776.197464] usb 1-1.3: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci_hcd
Jul  5 03:12:36 hdac kernel: [136786.356068] usb 1-1.3: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci_hcd
Jul  5 03:12:41 hdac kernel: [136791.517429] usb 1-1.3: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci_hcd
Jul  5 03:12:42 hdac kernel: [136791.965221] usb 1-1.3: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci_hcd
Jul  5 03:12:42 hdac kernel: [136792.412974] usb 1-1.3: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci_hcd
Jul  5 03:12:43 hdac kernel: [136792.900701] usb 1-1.3: reset high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci_hcd
Jul  5 03:12:43 hdac kernel: [136793.316865] scsi 7:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
Jul  5 03:12:43 hdac kernel: [136793.317120] usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 11
Jul  5 03:12:43 hdac kernel: [136793.388401] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 12 using ehci_hcd
Jul  5 03:12:44 hdac kernel: [136793.836359] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 13 using ehci_hcd
Jul  5 03:12:44 hdac kernel: [136794.283982] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 14 using ehci_hcd
Jul  5 03:12:45 hdac kernel: [136794.776418] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 15 using ehci_hcd
Jul  5 07:46:51 hdac rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.11" x-pid="2234" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] rsyslogd was HUPed
Jul  5 07:46:51 hdac kernel: [153233.051604] md: super_written gets error=-19, uptodate=0
Jul  5 07:46:51 hdac kernel: [153233.080561] lost page write due to I/O error on md0
Jul  5 07:46:51 hdac kernel: [153233.082218] lost page write due to I/O error on md0
Jul  5 07:46:51 hdac kernel: [153233.088909] lost page write due to I/O error on md0
Jul  5 07:46:51 hdac kernel: [153233.088972] lost page write due to I/O error on md0
Jul  5 07:46:51 hdac kernel: [153233.089030] lost page write due to I/O error on md0
Jul  5 07:46:51 hdac kernel: [153233.089084] lost page write due to I/O error on md0
Jul  5 07:46:51 hdac kernel: [153233.089139] lost page write due to I/O error on md0
Jul  5 07:46:51 hdac kernel: [153233.089193] lost page write due to I/O error on md0
Jul  5 07:46:51 hdac kernel: [153233.089247] lost page write due to I/O error on md0
Jul  5 07:46:51 hdac kernel: [153233.089300] lost page write due to I/O error on md0
Jul  5 07:46:52 hdac kernel: [153233.308299] md: super_written gets error=-19, uptodate=0
Jul  5 15:04:02 hdac kernel: [179450.340233] md: super_written gets error=-19, uptodate=0
Jul  5 15:04:02 hdac kernel: [179450.340549] quiet_error: 101 callbacks suppressed
Jul  5 15:04:02 hdac kernel: [179450.340566] lost page write due to I/O error on md0
Jul  5 15:04:02 hdac kernel: [179450.340774] lost page write due to I/O error on md0
Jul  5 15:04:03 hdac kernel: [179450.541182] md: super_written gets error=-19, uptodate=0
Jul  5 15:04:08 hdac kernel: [179455.698562] md: super_written gets error=-19, uptodate=0
Jul  5 15:04:08 hdac kernel: [179455.699059] lost page write due to I/O error on md0
Jul  5 15:04:08 hdac kernel: [179455.902387] md: super_written gets error=-19, uptodate=0
Jul  5 15:04:32 hdac kernel: [179479.848336] md: super_written gets error=-19, uptodate=0
Jul  5 15:04:32 hdac kernel: [179479.848803] lost page write due to I/O error on md0
Jul  5 15:04:32 hdac kernel: [179479.848832] lost page write due to I/O error on md0
Jul  5 15:04:32 hdac kernel: [179480.049689] md: super_written gets error=-19, uptodate=0
Jul  5 15:20:11 hdac kernel: [180418.849041] md: super_written gets error=-19, uptodate=0
Jul  5 15:20:11 hdac kernel: [180418.852710] lost page write due to I/O error on md0
Jul  5 15:20:12 hdac kernel: [180419.056405] md: super_written gets error=-19, uptodate=0
```

Comment: Have you looked at the possibility that the power saving features may be at fault? I've had a couple USB devices that I've had to whitelist to prevent power saving from stopping.